# Mysql dump based on value of a specific column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mysql

I have a single MySql database where I'm saving multiple company records and also keeping a company_id in most of the tables where i want to distinguish the records based on the company. If I have 10 companies with ids 1 from 10 and I want to setup a new instance of MySql just for one company and take mysqldump of all the data "where company_id=3" but also keeping the check on reference in the other tables and their data.
I want to know how to take such a dump in this condition.
I can find all the tables where company_id is present using this query

" SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name LIKE 'company_id' "

I just want to dump company 3 data and the reference of tables where company_id=3 is present in other tables and restore it to a new instance.
My application is using Ruby on Rails with Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sharding` for the purpose. Making a new `shard` for every country perhaps.[Yammer](https://eng.yammer.com/sharding-a-large-rails-app/) has a very good article about this. You can also check out this Engine Yard's [post](https://blog.engineyard.com/2009/a-quick-primer-on-sharding-for-ruby-on-rails). [data_fabric](https://github.com/bpot/data_fabric) is a good gem for this purpose.

Comment: I have taken dump of the complete database but now i want only the details of company_id=3 and discard the data of other companies.My problem is how do I run a query where i can mention company_id=3

Comment: and you have this company_id across multiple tables, right?

Comment: Yes in a lot of tables, but i want to keep the check on those tables as well who have ids of tables which contain company_id

Comment: something like this
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query

Comment: I'd do it using a ruby script, which would include the tables you need to keep for the `company_id=3` and the associated data

Comment: I am using a ruby script where
tables="table1 table2 table3 table 4"
system("mysqldump -u.... -p... mydb #{tables} > domains.sql")

but this only gives me dump where company_id is present i want dump of just one company not all and also the related tables data
i am trying to do it based on MYSQL not activerecord

Comment: what you can do it to replicate your current database to another one and truncate all the irrelevant data(i.e. all data other than company_id 3). This shall server as a dump for the specific data you want

Comment: The database size is huge and it takes a lot of time for dump. this is the reason i want to just pick out the details required not whole dump.